# Why is my Qt widget's focus being changed?

Tags: c++, qt

I basically have a function that checks for focus in's/out's of a lineEdit. From here it does a text animation to make the input look in a "Google" style. Here's the function:

```
QParallelAnimationGroup *group = new QParallelAnimationGroup;

QPropertyAnimation *posAnimation = new QPropertyAnimation(label, "pos");
posAnimation->setStartValue(QPoint(0, 0));
posAnimation->setEndValue(QPoint(5, 5));
group->addAnimation(posAnimation);

QPropertyAnimation *sizeAnimation = new QPropertyAnimation(label, "size");
sizeAnimation->setStartValue(label->size());
sizeAnimation->setEndValue(QSize(QFontMetrics(pix16).width(label->text()), QFontMetrics(pix16).height()));
group->addAnimation(sizeAnimation);

QPropertyAnimation *fontAnimation = new QPropertyAnimation(label, "fontPixelSize");
fontAnimation->setStartValue(12);
fontAnimation->setEndValue(16);
group->addAnimation(fontAnimation);

group->start(QAbstractAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);

label->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents);

updateRect();
return lineEdit->eventFilter(watched, event);
```

The only issue is that
upon clicking from one lineEdit into another the focus goes away from the first (which is good) then it goes to the second, but quickly goes away from the second as well.

Not sure as to why this occurs, but it renders my animation worthless.

I am using the Qt 5.9 IDE with C++

EDIT: I sub-classed QLabel in order to get the custom property:

```
class Label: public QLabel {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY (double fontPixelSize READ fontPixelSize WRITE setFontPixelSize)

public:
    Label(QWidget* parent = 0): QLabel(parent)
    {

    }
    double fontPixelSize() const
    {
        return font().pixelSize();
    }
    Q_SLOT void setFontPixelSize(int size)
    {
        QFont f = font();
        f.setPixelSize(size);
        setFont(f);
    }
};
```

EDIT: Added GitHub link: [HERE](https://github.com/NickJohn547745/ChatManager)

Comment: when investigating the cause of the problem I suggest you to try first without animation and get the order of events using qDebug. I could join you in the search for the cause but the code you've shared does not helping me much to be able do that.

Comment: @scopchanov I will add the code to GitHub now.

Comment: @scopchanov I've edited the post to have a link to the entire source.

Comment: OK, I will take a look when I have time.

Comment: First impression (on x64, Windows 7, Qt 5.9, MSVC2017) - several LineEdits have focus simultaneously. I am searching further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I've found after examining the code from the link:

**Problem:** In the method `GFrame::updateRect` at least the call to `QWidget::adjustSize` is causing the focus to be stolen from the *QLineEdit*. Probably `setMinimumSize` has something to do with it as well, but I didn't test it.

**Solution:** I would advise you to comment both calls to `GFrame::updateRect` in `GFrame::eventFilter`. Then it should work as you expect.

Further advice: you may comment the calls to `QLineEdit::setFocus` in `GFrame::eventFilter` as well, as they are not necessary.

Comment: What can I do to allow the call to `setMinimumSize`

Comment: Let me try something and I will get back to you with the result.

Comment: Well, the call to `setMinimumSize` alone does not cause the focus to be stolen.

Comment: The call to `adjustSize` alone doesn't not cause the focus to be stolen either.

Comment: I am afraid I don't agree with you. In `GFrame::eventFilter` comment both calls to `updateRect` and it will work as expected. Then substitute them with calls to `adjustSize` and the problem is back.

Comment: When un-commenting the call to `updateRect` and commenting the call to `adjustSize` the problem still occurs.

Comment: I must admit you are right. It seems that when the GFrame is resized for whatever reason, the focus is stolen from the QLineEdit. I will see if I could came up with an idea how to solve that.

Comment: @Nicholas Johnson, I've palyed around with it a little bit and managed to get it work using a fixed height and then in updateRect setting the minimum width instead of the minimum size. Is it OK if the height is fixed?

Comment: I guess so. The height was used to calculate how tall the parent QFrame should be.

Comment: Then, if you don't expect a change in the font size, instead of calculating the height dynamically, just find a good value for it and fix it.

Comment: Well, to be honest, to answer this question I have to make a test stand and monitor the events for all widgets to see in which order they are issued and possibly find where exactly it does break. Is it really worth to do that?

Comment: Something I would rather do is to think about possible redesign of the widget in order to avoid the problem completely. Do you think that this makes any sense?

Comment: can you elaborate just a bit on the redesignation of the widget?

Comment: @Nicholas Johnson, let me prepare something for you and I will post the code, OK?

Comment: @Nicholas Johnson try this one and tell me what you think: https://github.com/scopchanov/LoginScreen

Comment: @Nicholas Johnson, please let me know whether the proposed redesign works for you.

Comment: @Nicholas Johnson, That's great!